# For which values of $a$ we will get two different roots?

Tags: systems-of-equations, roots, quadratics, absolute-value

In given the following system of equations:
$$ |x-1| > 2x+2 $$
$$ x^2 + ax + a -1 = 0 $$
For which values of $a$ we will get two different roots?

Comment: Use the fact that we get two different real roots when $b^2-4ac \gt 0.$

Comment: What do you need the first inequality for?

Answer (score 1):

The first gives
$$x-1>2x+2$$ or $$x-1<-2x-2,$$ which gives $$x<-\frac{1}{3}.$$
Now, let $f(x)=x^2+ax+a-1$ and solve the following system:
$$f\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)>0$$
$$-\frac{a}{2}<-\frac{1}{3}$$ and
$$a^2-4(a-1)>0.$$

Comment: Why you want that $f(-\frac{1}{3}) > 0 $ ?

Comment: @StackUser Because we need that roots of the quadratic equation would be less that $-\frac{1}{3}.$ Draw the graph of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation has two roots $x_1=-1$ and $x_2=1-a$. It is easy to see $x_1\neq x_2$ if $a\neq 2$.

Clearly if $x=x_1$, then the inequality $|x-1|>2x+2$ holds. For $x=x_2$, then the inequality $|x-1|>2x+2$ becomes
$$ |a|>4-2a. \tag{1}$$
If $a\ge2$, (1) holds. If $0\le a<2$, then the solution of (1) is $\frac43<a<2$. If $a<0$, then (1) does not hold.

So if $\frac43<a<2$, the equation has two different roots satisfying the inequality.